# Remember App-Engine Sign-In on IOS Devices

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0

I've been following [this Google page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_ios) that describes how to authenticate under IOS to an App-Engine (cloud endpoint) backend.  That's fine.  However, it seems to require signing in anew with each run of my program.

Is there any way to

1. skip the signin/authentication web-view in favor of some global resource,
2. remember previous signin/authentication information and re-use it, or
3. simplify the signin/authentication procedure by remembering the previous username

It would be nice if the IOS version could behave like the Android version which, of course, does not need a sign-in step because it's handled directly by the OS.

Thanks!

Comment: Brian - Did you find a solution to this? I'm looking for the best practices for the same thing.

Comment: No, I haven't.  I'm still working with the simulator instead of a real device and was hoping things would be better on an actual iPad.  (small hope)  For development, I've added a bunch of `#ifdef` constants I can enable that avoids having to talk with my server.  I can test most things without signing in.

Comment: @Ryan, I've now worked it out.  See supplied answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now worked this out.  Not sure how I missed it in the documentation during my first pass.

See "Retrieving Authorization from the Keychain" at https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication* auth =
    [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch
        authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:AUTH_KEYCHAIN_NAME
                                clientID:IOS_CLIENT_ID
                            clientSecret:IOS_CLIENT_SECRET];
if ([auth canAuthorize]) {
    // add existing auth to our GTLServiceFoo, cleverly named "fooEndpoint"
    [fooEndpoint setAuthorizer:auth];
} else {
    // go through sign-in dialog flow and add the auth resulting from that
    ...
}
```